# Working with date and times in Renjin

Tags: r, renjin

I'm a bit lost, how can I pass to renjin an array of datetime (going though string would be really a pain). It can be a Joda or Java dateTime class or similar

I haven't found either a datetime type.

Comment: Are you looking to pass java.util.Date instances from Java to Renjin?

Comment: it's a list of joda datetimes actually, but I can use both structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R language doesn't have a special date/time vector type; there are a few different representations depending on how time is modelled:

1. **POSIXct**: stored as double vector of class "POSIXct" with the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970. See the [PosixCtVector.Builder](http://javadoc.renjin.org/latest/org/renjin/primitives/time/PosixCtVector.Builder.html) Java class for a convenient way of constructing an R object.
2. **POSIXlt:** stored as a list of date-time component vectors. See [PosixLtVector.Builder](http://javadoc.renjin.org/latest/org/renjin/primitives/time/PosixLtVector.Builder.html)
3. **Date**: stored as a double vector of class "Date" that contains the number of days since 1970-01-01 IIRC.